# Number of parameters in MCMC

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc, mcmc

I want to sample from my posterior distribution using the `pymc` package.

I am wondering if there is a limit on the number of dimensions such algorithm can handle. My log likelihood is the sum of 3 Gaussians and 1 mixture of Gaussians. I have approx `750 parameters` in my model. Can `pymc` handle such a big number of parameters?

Comment: Try it and find out.  Happy to help if you run into trouble.

Comment: I am talking from a theoretical point of view. I was working with `emcee` first, and it turned out that it does not handle more than 30 parameters! So I want to check how many dimensions does `pymc` handles.

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran (successfully) a model with 2,958 parameters. It was on a 8 Gb Windows machine. You should be fine with 750.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I ended up using PyStan. However it would be interesting to compare the results from Pystan to pymc. Thanks!